# How to install system packages into oracle?

Tags: oracle, system-administration

I am creating a copy of our testing Oracle DB (10g both) and run into a problem in that our testing database has UTL_SMTP and UTL_FILE system packages installed and my local OracleXE version does not.  Our system administrator has gone home for the day and given his state earlier I really would rather not bother him.

How do I get these packages on my local OracleXE instance?  I need to know where to download them as well as how to install them.  Hopefully granting permissions I can figure out myself ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Files are:

$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlsmtp.sql
$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlfile.sql

Run as SYS in SQL*Plus

Comment: "Run" as SYS can be done like this: @/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/rdbms/admin/utlfile.sql (changing path as needed)